# Issue with CodeIgniter Form Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

As usually, I set the rules for form validation, and if they don't pass I use `$this->load->view()` and load the form again.

Everything works fine with Firefox and Opera. But in all others browsers, when the form validation doesn't pass and the form is loaded again, the document gets unformatted. I used HTML Tidy to check if I missed and closing tag or something, but everything is fine.

I also checked the source code with W3C HTML5 Validator. The document passed with no errors. Then, I ran the form validation and checked the same source code again. The validator trew 5 errors this time.

```
 Line 2, Column 1: Non-space characters found without seeing a doctype first. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>.
<!DOCTYPE html>

 Line 2, Column 1: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.
<!DOCTYPE html>
Content model for element head:
If the document is an iframe srcdoc document or if title information is available from a higher-level protocol: Zero or more elements of metadata content.
Otherwise: One or more elements of metadata content, of which exactly one is a title element.

 Line 2, Column 16: Stray doctype.
<!DOCTYPE html>

 Line 3, Column 19: Stray start tag html.
<html lang="pt-br">

 Line 3, Column 19: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
<html lang="pt-br">
```

I know that when there is something before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` things can get bad. But I don't have any variable there. Maybe CI is generating something.

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Check your tags in the <head> section are spelt and closed correctly, an example of your HTML code would help a lot.

Comment: If your problem is solved, plaese post your solution as an answer and accept it (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: If I could post my answer I would! This is my first question. People close, edit it, do whatever they want with it. I don't have control of my stuff. Now I can't delete it. What's wrong with I'm being able to have full control over it? The answer is, I hd files UTF-8 with BOM andd then I saved the files to UTF-8 without BOM and everything now works fine.

Comment: @RGutter Wait patiently, this question was nominated to reopen.

Comment: @RGutter Now the question is reopened, you can post your solution.

Comment: @GaborSch Thank you! I'll post it.

Comment: @RGutter I was not my own merit, but the community opened it. I hope you will enjoy StackOverflow. It would worth reading through the FAQ, so you will know what you can expect.

Comment: @GaborSch Ok! Thanks anyway! :) I've been using StackOverflow for some time already, but only consulting questions. This website helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I had two UTF-8 with BOM files in my application.
So, if the form validation returns false and the view is reloaded, the set of bytes `EF BB BF` was added at the beginning of the document, before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` causing those errors.
So I saved the two files to UTF-8 without BOM encoding, and now everything is working normally.